# How to get maximum value of a specific part of strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have below records

```
Id         Title 
500006     FS/97/98/037                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
500007     FS/97/04/035                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
500008     FS/97/01/036                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
500009     FS/97/104/040
```

I should split `Title` field and get 4th part of text and return maximum value. In this example my query should return `040` or `40`.

Comment: Does your data always contain 4 parts of text?

Comment: yes It's always 4 parts.

Answer (score 4):

```
select max(cast(right(Title, charindex('/', reverse(Title) + '/') - 1) as int))
from your_table
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a1faa/4)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split the data in the `Title` column and get the part from the splitted text by position, you may try with one JSON-based approach with a simple string transformation. You need to transform the data in the `Title` column into a valid JSON array (FS/97/98/037 into ["FS","97","08","037"]) and after that to parse thе data with `OPENJSON()`. The result from `OPENJSON()` (using default schema and parsing `JSON` array) is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`, and the `key` column holds the index of the items in the `JSON` array:

Note, that using `STRING_SPLIT()` is not an option here, because the order of the returned rows is not guaranteed.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   Id varchar(6),
   Title varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (Id, Title)
VALUES
   ('500006', 'FS/97/98/037'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   ('500007', 'FS/97/04/035'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   ('500008', 'FS/97/01/036'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   ('500009', 'FS/97/104/040')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT MAX(j.[value])
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(d.Title, '/', '","'), '"]')) j
WHERE (j.[key] + 1) = 4
```

If you data has fixed format with 4 parts, even this approach may help:

```
SELECT MAX(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Title, '/', '.'), 1))
FROM Data
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`PARSENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function since you always have 4 parts(confirmed in comments section)

```
select max(cast(parsename(replace(Title,'/','.'),1) as int)) 
   from yourtable
```

Comment: I think that you need to replace `/` with `.` to use `PARSENAME` correctly.

Comment: @juergend overlooked the `/`, fixed.

Comment: @Zhorov - yep, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below query.

```
SELECT Top 1 
    CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Title,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[4]','int') as Value
from Data
order by 1 desc
```

You can find the live demo [**Here**](https://rextester.com/EGVGEL19809).